# Vue - same navbar and footer in multiple applications

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I would like to create multiple SPA with the same navbar and footer but the problem is...
if i have to change the template of these components how can i do to change it only once and not in all the applications? can it be done?
right now in each project i copy the files navbar.vue and footer.vue but by doing so in case of modification i have to edit all the files in each project and recompile. it is a big problem.
My idea is to create a site with multiple subdomain and for each subdomain to have same navbar and footer. Each subdomain is a SPA.

I thought about calling an api with axios that returns some html and putting it into the component before it is created, could that be a way?

Comment: To achieve this you have to create a shared component as a library. So that you can use it in all your applications by importing in `package.json` file.

Comment: but also in this case i need to recompile project...

Comment: Yes but you have to make changes at one place instead in each project.